# Can someone explain me this loop in php? I can't understand why $a gets value 20

Tags: php, loops

translation of the exercise: There is a code snippet in PHP. After the loop is over, the variable a gets value

[image]

Comment: `$i` starts at 10, `$a` at 0. Every iteration subtracts 1 from `$i` and adds 2 to `$a`. Once `$i` reaches 0 the loop ends because 0 type-juggles to false.

Comment: 10 iteration with $a +2 in each 10*2=20

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$a` starts out as 0 and `$i` as 10.

The code inside the `while` loop will run as long as the expression inside the `()` is true. In PHP, any number that isn't `0` is considered `true`.

Each time the loop runs (or as we say, each "iteration of the loop", two things happen:

1. `$a` is set to `$a + 2`. In other words, $a is now whatever it was before, plus 2.
2. `$i` is "decremented" by 1. In other words, $i is now whatever it was before, minus 1.

Here are the values of each variable at the end of each iteration:

| Iteration | Value of $a | Value of $i |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 + 2 = 2 | 10 - 1 = 9 |
| 2 | 2 + 2 = 4 | 9 - 1 = 8 |
| 3 | 4 + 2 = 6 | 8 - 1 = 7 |
| 4 | 6 + 2 = 8 | 7 - 1 = 6 |
| 5 | 8 + 2 = 10 | 6 - 1 = 5 |
| 6 | 10 + 2 = 12 | 5 - 1 = 4 |
| 7 | 12 + 2 = 14 | 4 - 1 = 3 |
| 8 | 14 + 2 = 16 | 3 - 1 = 2 |
| 9 | 16 + 2 = 18 | 2 - 1 = 1 |
| 10 | 18 + 2 = 20 | 1 - 1 = 0 |

Since `$i` is now 0, the expression in the `()` is considered `false`, so the loop stops, and the value of `$a` is 20.